# Why doesn't my local variables change in value, despite being called in my functions?

Tags: python, function, variables, turtle-graphics

In the program that I am trying to create, I am using Turtle to create a 12-hour digital alarm clock, where each number(hh:mm), changes as if the clock is going through a 24-hour day. However, some of the variables that I am using to set the number for the minutes and the one's place hour hand, are not changing in value, even though I have set them up to add them up once certain conditions are met.

So basically, I have set up turtles to draw a desk, and the body and the face of the clock on that desk. But more importantly, I made 6 turtles, one for the dots in between the hour numbers and minute numbers, one for AM/PM, and one for each of the numbers. They are all drawn by separate functions for each of the turtles that I described above. I have a separate .txt document which lines of 5 bits, corresponding to the points where each number hand needed to change. With the AM/PM and the ten's place hour number function, I have set up a basic if and else statement, where if the bit that corresponded with that specific function came out as 0, the ten's place would should come out as a 0, or if the bit came out as 1, it would come out as 1. However, for the rest of the numbers if the bit came out as 0, then the corresponding function would repeat the last drawing it did, which would saved in its own function. If the bit came out as 1 though, it would be saved in a variable, which will then be used in a modulus operation with another variable that would produce a number that would correspond with the next number of the cycle or rotation. For example, for the one's place minute hand, the numbers that can appear are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9. If the modulus operation turns out a 3, then the number would be a  3. As well, the 3 would be saved in a variable so that, when the bit came out as a 0, then the function can show the number before. Also, if the modulus operation came out as a 0, then the second variable that I described in the modulus function would be add with a certain number each time. In the one's place minute hand's case, that number is 10. So that is all. My code is below:

```
#Program Setup
import turtle
import time
num = turtle.Turtle()
num2 = turtle.Turtle()
num3 = turtle.Turtle()
num4 = turtle.Turtle()
text = turtle.Turtle()
binlist = []
com = 12
com1 = 6
com2 = 10
bits = 0
bits1 = 0
bits2 = 0
#Function Setup
def hour1(bit1,g):
    if int(bit1) == 0:
        num.clear()
        g = num.write("0",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
    else:
        num.clear()
        g = num.write("1",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
def hour2(bit2,g1,bits,com):
    if int(bit2) == 0:
        num2.clear()
        g1
    else:
        bits +=1
        return bits
        if int(bits) % int(com) == 1:
            num2.clear()
            g1 = num2.write("1",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % int(com) == 2:
            num2.clear()
            g1 = num2.write("2",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % int(com) == 3:
            num2.clear()
            g1 = num2.write("3",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % int(com) == 4:
            num2.clear()
            g1 = num2.write("4",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % int(com) == 5:
            num2.clear()
            g1 = num2.write("5",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % int(com) == 6:
            num2.clear()
            g1 = num2.write("6",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % int(com) == 7:
            num2.clear()
            g1 = num2.write("7",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % int(com) == 8:
            num2.clear()
            g1 = num2.write("8",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % int(com) == 9:
            num2.clear()
            g1 = num2.write("9",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % int(com) == 10:
            num2.clear()
            g1 = num2.write("0",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % int(com) == 11:
            num2.clear()
            g1 = num2.write("1",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        else:
            num2.clear()
            g1 = num2.write("2",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
            com += 12
            return com
def min1(bit3,g2,bits1,com1):
    if int(bit3) == 0:
        num3.clear()
        g2
    else:
        bits1 += 1
        return bits1
        if int(bits1) % int(com1) == 1:
            num3.clear()
            g2 = num3.write("1",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits1) % int(com1) == 2:
            num3.clear()
            g2 = num3.write("2",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits1) % int(com1) == 3:
            num3.clear()
            g2 = num3.write("3",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits1) % int(com1) == 4:
            num3.clear()
            g2 = num3.write("4",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits1) % int(com1) == 5:
            num3.clear()
            g2 = num3.write("5",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        else:
            num3.clear()
            g2 = num3.write("0",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
            com1 += 6
            return com1
def min2(bit4,g3,bits2,com2):
    if int(bit4) == 0:
        g3
    else:
        bits2 += 1
        return bits2
        if int(bits2) % int(com2) == 1:
            num4.clear()
            g3 = num4.write("1",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % int(com2) == 2:
            num4.clear()
            g3 = num4.write("2",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % int(com2) == 3:
            num4.clear()
            g3 = num4.write("3",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % int(com2) == 4:
            num4.clear()
            g3 = num4.write("4",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % int(com2) == 5:
            num4.clear()
            g3 = num4.write("5",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % int(com2) == 6:
            num4.clear()
            g3 = num4.write("6",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % int(com2) == 7:
            num4.clear()
            g3 = num4.write("7",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % int(com2) == 8:
            num4.clear()
            g3 = num4.write("8",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % int(com2) == 9:
            num4.clear()
            g3 = num4.write("9",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        else:
            num4.clear()
            g3 = num4.write("0",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
            com2 += 10
            return com2
def meridiem(bit5,g4):
    if int(bit5) == 0:
        text.clear()
        g4 = text.write("AM",False,"center",("alarm clock",25,"normal"))
    else:
        text.clear()
        g4 = text.write("AM",False,"center",("alarm clock",25,"normal"))
f = open("ikeokereke.txt","r")
for line in f:
    binlist.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
for e in binlist:
    bit1 = e[0:1]
    bit2 = e[1:2]
    bit3 = e[2:3]
    bit4 = e[3:4]
    bit5 = e[4:5]
    time.sleep(.5)
    hour1(bit1,g)
    hour2(bit2,g1,bits,com)
    min1(bit3,g2,bits1,com1)
    min2(bit4,g3,bits2,com2)
    meridiem(bit5,g4)
    print(bits)
    print(bits1)
    print(bits2)
    print(com)
    print(com1)
    print(com2)
```

Expected result: Normal, functioning digital alarm clock
Actual result: The ten's place hour hand appearing as a 0, and the one's place minute hand appearing as a 0, and the other two numbers not even appearing at all.

ikeokereke.txt

https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vT6O_NqKrKR0tC8IPvoItwmJL0uCgbUJsBK0xH62IHAfx_nJxD62DuKjc8Ih93YyMKsNGn0EP6Nxu6Q/pub

Comment: Add the content of your ikeokereke.txt file to the question so we can run the code in order to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Even this small snippet of code has lots of problems:

```
def hour2(bit2,g1,bits,com):
    if int(bit2) == 0:
        num2.clear()
        g1
    else:
        bits +=1
        return bits
        if int(bits) % int(com) == 1:
            ...
```

Specifically:

- `g1` is never defined anywhere so the call `hour2(bit2,g1,bits,com)` can't work.
- are there any possible values for `g1` that would make sense for putting `g1` on a line by itself as part of your code?
- incrementing `bits` and returning it doesn't make sense as nothing looks at the return value of the `hour2()` call and if `bits` is meant as the global variable, this won't work as there is no `global` statement in the function.
- the thirty or so lines of code after the `return bits` statement will never get executed as you've left the function.
- both `bits` and `com` are already integers so calling `int()` on them over and over again seems to indicate a lack of understanding of your own design.

Comment: Concerning the g1 variable, it is first set during within the #Main Program part of the code. I only gave you the for loops at the end of my program.

Comment: As well, with the line of g1 on its own, I wasn't sure how to repeat a previous drawing, without setting that value to that value directly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by having the variables be incremented in the for loops instead of the functions themselves. The change in the code is below:

```
#Program Setup
import turtle
import time
#...
num = turtle.Turtle()
num2 = turtle.Turtle()
num3 = turtle.Turtle()
num4 = turtle.Turtle()
circles = turtle.Turtle()
text = turtle.Turtle()
binlist = []
bits = 0
bits1 = 0
bits2 = 0
firsthour = True
#Function Setup
#...
def hour1(bit1):
    if int(bit1) == 0:
        num.clear()
        num.write("0",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
    else:
        num.clear()
        num.write("1",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
def hour2(bit2,bits,firsthour):
    if int(bit2) == 0:
        if firsthour == True:
            num2.write("2",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        else:
            num2.clear()
            num2.write(,False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
    else:
        if int(bits) % 12 == 1:
            num2.clear()
            num2.write("1",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % 12 == 2:
            num2.clear()
            num2.write("2",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % 12 == 3:
            num2.clear()
            num2.write("3",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % 12 == 4:
            num2.clear()
            num2.write("4",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % 12 == 5:
            num2.clear()
            num2.write("5",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % 12 == 6:
            num2.clear()
            num2.write("6",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % 12 == 7:
            num2.clear()
            g1 = num2.write("7",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % 12 == 8:
            num2.clear()
            num2.write("8",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % 12 == 9:
            num2.clear()
            num2.write("9",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % 12 == 10:
            num2.clear()
            num2.write("0",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits) % 12 == 11:
            num2.clear()
            num2.write("1",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        else:
            num2.clear()
            num2.write("2",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
def min1(bit3,bits1):
    if int(bit3) == 0:
        num3.clear()
        num3.write(,False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
    else:
        if int(bits1) % 6 == 1:
            num3.clear()
            num3.write("1",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits1) % 6 == 2:
            num3.clear()
            num3.write("2",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits1) % 6 == 3:
            num3.clear()
            num3.write("3",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits1) % 6 == 4:
            num3.clear()
            num3.write("4",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits1) % 6 == 5:
            num3.clear()
            num3.write("5",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        else:
            num3.clear()
            num3.write("0",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
def min2(bit4,bits2):
    if int(bit4) == 0:
        num4.clear()
        num4.write(str(bits2),False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
    else:
        if int(bits2) % 10 == 1:
            num4.clear()
            num4.write("1",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % 10 == 2:
            num4.clear()
            num4.write("2",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % 10 == 3:
            num4.clear()
            num4.write("3",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % 10 == 4:
            num4.clear()
            num4.write("4",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % 10 == 5:
            num4.clear()
            num4.write("5",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % 10 == 6:
            num4.clear()
            num4.write("6",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % 10 == 7:
            num4.clear()
            num4.write("7",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % 10 == 8:
            num4.clear()
            num4.write("8",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        elif int(bits2) % 10 == 9:
            num4.clear()
            num4.write("9",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
        else:
            num4.clear()
            num4.write("0",False,"center",("alarm clock",100,"normal"))
def dots():
    circles.speed(0)
    circles.dot(20,"red")
    circles.penup()
    circles.left(90)
    circles.forward(50)
    circles.pendown()
    circles.dot(20,"red")
    circles.hideturtle()
def meridiem(bit5):
    if int(bit5) == 0:
        text.clear()
        text.write("AM",False,"center",("alarm clock",25,"normal"))
    else:
        text.clear()
        text.write("PM",False,"center",("alarm clock",25,"normal"))

#Main Program
#...
f = open("ikeokereke.txt","r")
for line in f:
    binlist.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
for e in binlist:
    bit1 = e[0:1]
    bit2 = e[1:2]
    bit3 = e[2:3]
    bit4 = e[3:4]
    bit5 = e[4:5]
    time.sleep(.5)
    if int(bit2) == 1:
        bits += 1
    if int(bit3) == 1:
        bits1 += 1
    if int(bit4) == 1:
        bits2 += 1
    if int(bits) == 1:
        firsthour = False
    hour1(bit1)
    hour2(bit2,bits,firsthour)
    min1(bit3,bits1)
    min2(bit4,bits2)
    meridiem(bit5)
```